# Pandas multiindex dataframe - Selecting max from one index within multiindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I've got a dataframe with a multi index of Year and Month like the following

```
     |     |Value
Year |Month|  
     |  1  |  3
1992 |  2  |  5
     |  3  |  8
     | ... | ...
1993 |  1  |  2
     | ... | ...
```

I'm trying to select the maximum Value for each year and put that in a DF like this:

```
     | Max
Year |  
1992 |  5
1993 |  2
     | ...
```

There's not much info on multi-indexes, should I simply do a group by and apply or something similar to make it more simple?

Comment: Please fix your example though: there's no way the max Value for 1992 can be 5, since it is 8 in Month=3. Are you looking for max or idxmax (the Month  giving the largest max Value?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly right:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(max)
```

In my sample `DataFrame`:

```
                     0
Caps Lower            
A    a     0  0.246490
           1 -1.265711
           2 -0.477415
           3 -0.355812
           4 -0.724521
     b     0 -0.409198
           1 -0.062552
           2 -0.731789
           3  1.131616
           4  0.085248
B    a     0  0.193948
           1  2.010710
           2  0.289300
           3  0.305373
           4  1.376965
     b     0  0.210522
           1  1.431279
           2 -0.247171
           3  0.899074
           4  0.639926
```

Result:

```
             0
Caps          
A     1.131616
B     2.010710
```

This is how I created the `DataFrame`, by the way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), columns = l)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns, names=['Caps','Lower'])
df = pd.DataFrame(df.unstack())
```

Comment: Anyone know how to make the example data at the end of this answer work?  `columns = l` raises an exception for me as `l` isn't defined.  I tried to infer what it might be but no luck.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS METHOD. Does it work? Yes, BUT it's way slower than simply doing this `df.groupby(level=0).max()`

Answer (score 8):

Simplier solution is [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) only:

```
#bernie's sample data
df = df.max(level=0)
print (df)
             0
Caps          
A     1.131616
B     2.010710
```