# Selecting row by maximum value from hierachical DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {('California', 2000): [33871648, 45],
        ('California', 2010): [37253956, 52],
        ('Texas', 2000): [20851820, 56],
        ('Texas', 2010): [25145561, 34],
        ('New York', 2000): [18976457, 23],
        ('New York', 2010): [19378102, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.index.names = 'State', 'Year'
df.columns = ['population', 'foo']
print(df)

                 population  foo
State      Year                 
California 2000    33871648   45
           2010    37253956   52
Texas      2000    20851820   56
           2010    25145561   34
New York   2000    18976457   23
           2010    19378102   23
```

I want the rows with the maximum `foo` for each `State`, but if I try

```
idx = df.groupby(level=0)['foo'].apply(np.argmax)
print(df.loc[idx])
```

When I try to group by level 0 and apply `np.argmax`, I get a warning:

```
... FutureWarning: 
The current behaviour of 'Series.argmax' is deprecated, use 'idxmax'
instead.
The behavior of 'argmax' will be corrected to return the positional
maximum in the future. For now, use 'series.values.argmax' or
'np.argmax(np.array(values))' to get the position of the maximum
row.
  return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
                 population  foo
State      Year                 
California 2010    37253956   52
New York   2000    18976457   23
Texas      2000    20851820   56
```

It works, but how should I be doing this properly? I'm not sure I understand the suggestions in the warning message.
This question is a bit like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163296/pandas-multiindex-dataframe-selecting-max-from-one-index-within-multiindex) but I want the entire row, not just the maximum values.

Comment: what about level1 when `foo` is same? you want the max of that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform('max')` and then compare with `foo` and keep the records which matches the condition:

```
df[df.foo.eq(df.groupby(level=0)['foo'].transform('max'))]
```

---

```
                 population  foo
State      Year                 
California 2010    37253956   52
Texas      2000    20851820   56
New York   2000    18976457   23
           2010    19378102   23
```

Comment: Since the original question doesn't show both lines for `New York`, it's possible that duplicates are not desired.  If you only want the first result, you should probably append: `.drop_duplicates(["State", "foo"], keep="first")`.

Comment: OK... that works. I've just noticed that `df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['foo'].idxmax()]` does too. Is there any reason to prefer one solution over the other?

Comment: @xnx that gives slightly different output as this solution will group `level=0` so it doesnt drop `level=` where `foo` is same. You stated "I want the rows with the maximum foo for each State" for which this is the correct sol(IMO). You can test the timings though